# how to zoom image inside ion-scroll

Tags: ionic2

I am working on Ionic2 app. I want to zoom an image inside ion-scroll. How can I do that.

```
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" zoom=true>
      <img src="https://aa.com/app/package_content/s78c_e4vt6/main_images/pg_114.jpg" />
  </ion-scroll>
```

Comment: I think this : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/zoom-on-image-in-ionic-2/45910 will help you. Let me know if it does.

Answer (score 1):

I can zoom an image inside an ion-scroll by writing a small code for the tap event. This code is tested and working in android/ios ionic 2. Tap one time to zoom in and tap again to zoom out . For ios, just add overflow scroll in the ion-content for smooth scrolling.

.ts page:

```
  export class PageName {

constructor() {
}
public tap: number = 600;

tapEvent(e) {
    if (this.tap != 700) {
        this.tap = 700;
    }
    else
        this.tap = 600;
}}
```

html:

```
 <ion-content style="background-image:url(assets/img/image1.PNG); white-space: nowrap; overflow: scroll; overflow-x:scroll; height: 100%">
     <ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true" (tap)="tapEvent($event)" zoom="true" style="width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;">
       <div class="scroll-item" style="  width:100%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: scroll;">
            <img [ngStyle]="{'width' : tap + 'px', 'min-width' : tap + 'px'}" alt="logo" src="assets/img/image2.PNG">
       </div>    
    </ion-scroll>  </ion-content>
```

Comment: Cant I use CSS3 scale instead of 'width'?

Comment: I am using width to get a virtual zoom effect by changing it to 600px to 700px on tap. You can customize it to any property you wanna change on that event, just keep the expression inside the ng-style.